# Proof of distributivity in bicartesian closed categories using Yoneda embedding

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory

I want to prove that in a cartesian closed category with finite coproducts, the following distributivity law always holds:
$$ X \times (Y + Z) \cong (X \times Y) + (X \times Z) $$
In [Bicartesian closed category is distributive](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549212/326036), the OP specifically asks for proofs avoiding the Yoneda embedding.
I'm interested to know wheter the following proof using the contravariant Yoneda embedding $y$ defined by $X \mapsto \hom(X, -)$ is correct (specifically the last step):

By the properties of exponentials and the fact that $\hom$ preserves colimits in the first variable, we have:
$$y(X \times (Y + Z)) = \hom(X \times (Y + Z), -) \cong \hom(Y + Z, -^X) \cong \hom(Y, -^X) + \hom(Z, -^X) \cong \hom(X \times Y, -) + \hom(X \times Z, -) = y(X \times Y) + y(X \times Z) $$
Now, using the fact that any fully faitfhul functor reflects colimits, we conclude that $X \times (Y + Z) \cong (X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$.

I'm not so confident about this last assertion. The chain of equations above shows that $y(X \times (Y + Z))$ is *isomorphic* (but not equal) to the colimit of the coproduct diagram for $y(X \times Y)$ and $y(X \times Z)$. Is this (together with the fact that $y$ reflects colimits) enough to assert the conclusion, or am I missing some important details, e.g. the naturality of the above isomorphisms?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4833692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to a correct proof. The corrected version is the following.
$$y(X \times (Y + Z)) = \hom(X \times (Y + Z), -) \cong \hom(Y + Z, -^X) \cong \hom(Y, -^X) \times \hom(Z, -^X) \cong \hom(X \times Y, -) \times \hom(X \times Z, -) \cong \hom((X \times Y) + (X \times Z), -) = y((X \times Y) + (X \times Z))$$
In particular, the universal property of a coproduct involves a *product* of hom-sets, not a coproduct. Finally, one applies full faithfulness of the Yoneda embedding to directly obtain an isomorphism between $X \times (Y + Z)$ and $(X \times Y) + (X \times Z)$.